# Downloading and seeding multiple torrents with the same names in rTorrent

Tags: bittorrent, rtorrent

I'm attempting to download and then seed a set of torrents using rTorrent. Some of these torrents have the same name (`Alpha Release`), and contain files with the same names but whose content is different.

rTorrent, naturally, attempts to download torrents with the same name to the same path (`~/downloads/Alpha Release/`). The downloads clobber each other forever, constantly failing hash checks and re-downloading uselessly.

How is it possible to successfully download and seed multiple torrents with the same name in rTorrent?

---

It would be ideal to choose directory names based on the torrent's infohashes, such as:

```
~/downloads/de9f2c7fd25e1b3afad3e85a0bd17d9b100db4b3/
~/downloads/da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709/
```

*or*

```
~/downloads/de9f2c7fd25e1b3afad3e85a0bd17d9b100db4b3 Alpha Release/
~/downloads/da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709 Alpha Release/
```

Comment: Doesn't rTorrent or one of its variants support the rename operation? This [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3lt87.jpg) was taken from the Vuze client.

Comment: @harrymc I'm not sure; I didn't see a straightforward way to rename documented anywhere. If one exists, clear instructions would make a useful answer. However, I'm really hoping for something automatic.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work, but you could try downloading the torrents using magnet links with separate [`dn`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme#Parameters) (display name) parameters. For instance, `magnet:?xt=urn:btih:de9f2c7fd25e1b3afad3e85a0bd17d9b100db4b3&dn=Alpha+Release+1` and `magnet:?xt=urn:btih:da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709&dn=Alpha+Release+2`

Comment: @Vinayak Unfortunately, that does not help. rTorrent uses the real name once it's downloaded the metadata.

Answer (score 3):

The downloads have to be separated, and the easiest way to do that is to place them in separate dirs. This is achieved by loading them *stopped* (`load.normal`), then setting a different download path using `d.directory.set` via XMLRPC, or using Ctrl-O in the curses UI. Finally, start them.

For two downloads, obviously only one needs to be treated special – the other can remain at the default location.

For multi-file items, you can also use `d.directory_base.set` trickery to actually rename the root directory of the download – then the items share the default download directory, i.e. are siblings.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've come into the same problem some time ago, and there is an alternative option to do that. That is, you have to edit the torrent files separately. If those are folders that are with the same name, they can be edited directly from almost any torrent client. But if we talk about files, that would be impossible. So, in this case it would be handy to use an online torrent editor. I use a website called [Torrent Editor](http://torrenteditor.com/). You can edit everything from the torrent file, and download a new copy of the updated one. Now, if you don't have the torrent file, and you are downloading using a magnet link, just convert that magnet link to a torrent file using a website like http://magnet2torrent.me 
As for how to generate a hash for the different files, check [OnlineMD5](http://onlinemd5.com/)
You can replace each torrent file name with the appropriate hash and update and download the new torrent files after editing. 
Other than this, I don't think there is any other option.

Comment: That's interesting, but wouldn't help in most cases, like mine. I'm trying to download and seed an existing torrent; I can't create a new one with a new hash.

Comment: You are not creating the torrent in this case, you are editing one that you already have downloaded (and maybe someone else created). If you have the torrent file, edit it and put the hash values you can generate using only the name. And even if the name is the same, the hash value will change. Try this other site to do that: http://www.md5hashgenerator.com/

Comment: So, the steps would be: 1. Download all the torrent files you want to download and seed, 2. Edit each one of them renaming the file names with a hash value, 3. Open the torrent files for download & seed.

Comment: Editing the file names within the .torrent file will change the `info_hash` and then you are not participating in the same swarm as the other peers.

Comment: @Encombe, that is true. And if you don't have the file, you cannot download/seed it. But I was thinking something else... What if when opening the .torrent file, you add a space before the file, but not with the space bar as it will be removed, but with `Alt+255`. Using a space will "rename" the file, and you will be on the same swarm, since the `info_hash` will be the same. And the same with the other files, but with more spaces. And opening different .torrent files (with different `info_hash`), and with the "same name", will be possible to download and seed on the same swarm as others.

Comment: That sounds like a trick to 'fool' the torrent client and that's something else than editing the file names with *Torrent Editor* (which will inevitably change the `info_hash`).

Comment: I agree with you! And this will also 'fool' the system, since on the system they will appear as different files/folders.

Comment: @JeremyBanks, please try it, and if it works, I will update the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Stop the torrent with `^k`, then press `^o` and choose the new directory for your download, then hit `return`, and start your download with `^s`

Answer (score -2):

Not personally familiar with rTorrent, however, I beleive something kind of like what you want is available via the [RuTorrent frontend](https://github.com/Novik/ruTorrent) for rTorrent.